# Comment les Français se réfèrent-ils aux « millennials » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'ai vu récemment des références à la **génération Y**, est-ce la même chose que les « millennials » (c'est-à-dire la génération des enfants nés dans les années 1990-2000) chez les anglophones ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les *millenials* sont effectivement la génération Y, c'est-à-dire ceux qui sont nés entre le début des années 80 et le milieu des années 90 ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ration_Y)). Pour ceux qui sont nés entre les années 1990 et 2000, on parle plutôt de génération Z ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Z)).

Comment: Intéressant, je n'avais jamais entendu parlé de la génération Z...

Comment: On l'appelle aussi la génération sacrifiée :p

Comment: Drôle, mais je pensais fermement que les millenials sont nés _après_ 2000, et que la génération Y est née entre 1990 et 2000 ...?